# Getting CakePHP to work with existing "non-Cake" database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am building a new app based on multiple databases with many tables which don't follow any Cake conventions. I want to use CakePHP but I'm not sure if it's possible without the database in a Cake format.

Problems include:

- Tables not named as Cake expects
- Primary keys are not necessarily named `id` (e.g. it might be `order_id`)
- Foreign keys are not necessarily named like `other_table_id`

Changing the database tables is not an option.

Is it possible to manually configure the schema in each model so that Cake will then know how the model relationships need to work? Or should I just give up on using Cake?

Comment: Don't give dude @XuDing is absolutely right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes. you can still use CakePHP in your case.
Check out various Model attributes to fit your needs
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html.

e.g. 
**public $useTable = 'exmp'** can be used to configure what table to use.

**public $primaryKey = 'example_id';** can be used to configure the primary key's name

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this code sample............**
More detail here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html
<?php

class Example extends AppModel {

// Name of the model. If you do not specify it in your model file it will be set to the class name by constructor.
    public $name = 'Example';
// table name example
    public $useTable = example;
// example_id is the field name in the database
    public $primaryKey = 'example_id';

}
?>
```